# How to Bind to Property Which Resides in the App Xaml backend

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have a `Property` in my App.xaml.cs called `User` that holds the User details.
I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349034/dependency-property-in-app-xaml-cs) that you can't have a dependency property on the App class.

I chose to use App.cs because it is global to the entire program and this is used for access control, but any alternatives are welcome.

Now my question is how can I bind to this property from my UserControls and Windows.

```
IsEnabled="{Binding Path=User, Converter={StaticResource hasAccessConverter}, ConverterParameter=Mid}"
```

This obviously only works on a property on the `DataContext`. I want to access the property on the App.
Can someone show me an example of the binding to the App.xaml.cs property if I implement `INotifyChanged`?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

> I have read here that you can't have a dependency property on the App class.

Indeed you can't, because `Application` doesn't inherit from `DependencyObject`. However, it's not necessary : only the *target* property of a binding needs to be a dependency property.

If you want to bind to a property of your App class, you can do it like that :

```
IsEnabled="{Binding Path=User, Source={x:Static Application.Current}}"
```

Comment: Just a note that this in a no-can-do in Silverlight. x:Static and x:Type don't exist in the Silverlight world.

Comment: Remember to implement INotifyPopertyChanged to see the changes to that property reflected on the user interface.

Comment: In the above, you're binding a `bool` to a `User`, that doesn't make any sense. I assume you want to bind it to `User.IsEnabled` -- how would one do that?

Comment: @DmitriNesteruk, I agree, it doesn't seem to make much sense... I just took the code from the OP and changed it a little, but I forgot the converter along the way. Assuming there is a User.IsEnabled property, you could just use `Path=User.IsEnabled`; otherwise, you can use a converter just like in the OP's code.

Answer (score 4):

And to access it programatically in C# you can do this:

```
((App)Application.Current).YourMethod
((App)Application.Current).YourProperty
```

Answer (score -1):

You can bind declaratively in Silverlight  to Application.Current by using a custom converter.

See my blog post [here](http://shineasilverlight.wordpress.com/2010/01/01/accessing-members-in-app-as-a-xaml-resource/)

Comment: Lone link is [considered a poor answer](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) since it is meaningless by itself and target resource is not guaranteed to be alive in the future. [It would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.